# Typescript inheritance property

Tags: inheritance, typescript

The code is as below:

```
class BaseClass {
   propertyA: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>();
   constructor(message: string) {
      this.propertyA.subscribe((newValue)=>{
          console.log(newValue); // not run when change propertyA in ChildClassA instance.
      });
   }      
}
class ChildClassA extends BaseClass   {
   propertyA: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>(); //remove it, the issue is solved.
}
```

I noticed that when the ChildClassA has the same property named as the BaseClass, the subscription function for propertyA will not run. Remove that line of declaration in ChildClassA will solved the issue.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are reassigning `this.propertyA` in `ChildClassA` **after** assigning it in the `BaseClass`

When compiled to Javascript the code becomes

```
var BaseClass = (function () {
    function BaseClass(message) {
        this.propertyA = ko.observable();
        this.propertyA.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            console.log(newValue); // not run when change propertyA in ChildClassA instance.
        });
    }
    return BaseClass;
}());
var ChildClassA = (function (_super) {
    __extends(ChildClassA, _super);
    function ChildClassA() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.propertyA = ko.observable(); //remove it, the issue is solved.
    }
    return ChildClassA;
}(BaseClass));
```

See it in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20class%20BaseClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20propertyA%3A%20KnockoutObservable%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20ko.observable%3Cstring%3E()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.propertyA.subscribe((newValue)%3D%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(newValue)%3B%20%2F%2F%20not%20run%20when%20change%20propertyA%20in%20ChildClassA%20instance.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20ChildClassA%20extends%20BaseClass%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20propertyA%3A%20KnockoutObservable%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20ko.observable%3Cstring%3E()%3B%20%2F%2Fremove%20it%2C%20the%20issue%20is%20solved.%0D%0A%7D)

When instantiating `ChildClassA` you are calling `super` which calls the constructor of `BaseClass` which assigns `this.propertyA` and subscribes the listener. Fine. However right after the call to `super`, you are reassigning `this.propertyA` in `ChildClassA` constructor with the line

```
this.propertyA = ko.observable(); //remove it, the issue is solved.
```

Property initializations are moved to the constructor, after `super` calls.

There is no such thing as overriding properties (by inheritance) in Typescript.